# C - Freeing the allocated memory of the struct using a function with ** parameter

Tags: c, pointers, struct, free, dereference

So I've got a problem with a function that frees the allocated memory of a dictionary type.
Here's struct I use and function:

```
struct word_count_t {
    char *word;
    int counter; //how many times word was repeated
};

struct dictionary_t
{
    int size; //number of words
    int capacity; //capacity of wc
    struct word_count_t *wc; //pointer to words 
};


void destroy_dictionary(struct dictionary_t** d) 
{
    if(d == NULL) return;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < d->size; i++)
    {
        free(d->wc->word+i);
    }
    free(d->wc);
    free(d);
}
```

It was compilating when the function declaration was like this:

```
void destroy_dictionary(struct dictionary_t* d)
```

I don't know how to make dereference here if it's needed and get rid of errors like:

```
[Error] request for member 'size' in '* d', which is of pointer type 'dictionary_t*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)
```

Comment: The code is wrong *now*. Given the body of the function, the parameter should be a single-indirection as your last line shows. If that has errors, tell us what *those* were *verbatim*. If the requirements are to use double-indirection (`struct dictionary_t **`), then the entire body has to change, and all instances of `d` need to be replaced with `(*d)`. (except in the argument list itself, obviously).

Comment: The only reason for passing `struct dictionary_t **d` to the function is so that you can end the function with `*d = NULL;`.  If you don't do that, you should just pass a regular `struct dictionary_t *d` to the function to avoid the problems you're having.  One way to code the function with the pointer to pointer would be to use `struct dictionary *dp = *d;` at the top, and work with `dp` throughout except for the `*d = NULL;` line at the end.

Comment: Double `**` is often used when the function shall alter the value of a pointer passed to the function, i.e. when one would write `*d=NULL` in the last line. As you do not alter the value of the pointer, the double `**` rarely makes sense, and you should go  ahead with `void destroy_dictionary(struct dictionary_t* d)`

Answer (score 1):

Since `d` is double pointer it takes pointer address as its input. So first you need to reference pointer address which `d` is holding using * operator. you cannot directly reference `size` and `wc` members using `d`. I would suggest you to only use double pointer if you want to change the actual pointer.

You need to define your destroy_dictionary as below.

```
void destroy_dictionary(struct dictionary_t** d) 
{
   if(d==NULL || *d == NULL) return;
   int i;
   for(i=0; i<(*d)->size; i++)
   {
      free((*d)->wc->word+i);
   }
   free((*d)->wc);
   free(*d);
   *d = NULL:
}
```

Comment: @Amandin there is no need for this argument to be passed as double-indirection unless the intent was to null the callers pointer once you complete this. Therefore, I strongly advise you put `*d = NULL;` as the last line of the function.

Comment: @WhozCraig taken the suggestion .

Answer (score 1):

You need to dereference `d` first.

```
for (i = 0; i < (*d)->size; i++)
{
    free((*d)->wc->word+i);
}
```